# Storing object with DateTime key in Redis

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I want to store object in Redis where key is not integer Id but property of type DateTime. Is it possible? How to tell Redis which of the properties is key? Merely any property named 'Id'?

If I put object to cache like this:

```
var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost", 30050);
using (var myRedis = redisClient.As<MyObject>())
{
    myRedis.Store(myObject);
}
```

how can I get it later?

```
var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost", 30050);
using (var myRedis = redisClient.As<MyObject>())
{
    myRedis.GetById(?????????);
}
```

Comment: The key is not necessarily a property of the object. It can be anything. Redis is not a document oriented database or a relational database.

Comment: It does not make any sense to me. Perhaps you should add which language/framework/redis client you use. It is not a server side question.

Comment: I am using Redis for .NET - ServiceStack.Redis.dll

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamps as ints will work nicely in Redis. You might need extra information if you need time zone support.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your MyObject class as:

```
class MyObject : IHasId<DateTime>
{
  public DateTime Id {get;set;}
  .......
}
```

Then it should work fine. Redis doesn't care about what your "Id" is. The ServiceStack Typed redis client cares because it takes your "Id" property and uses that to store your object. If you want to use a datetime as your key, so be it.

You'd get it later by passing a datetime into client.GetById(). That said, seems like a somewhat tricky key to manage unless you define the granularity level of your datetime based key. By that I mean, you need to decide if you'll care only about the date portion, or if you'll care about the date + time down to the minute, or the date + time down to the second, etc.

Also - you should change your redis client code to:

```
using(var client = new RedisClient("..."))
{
         var myRedis = client.As<MyObject>();
         ......
}
```

The typed redis client returned by As() doesn't actually dispose of its connection, so your code as written would leave connections open.